# Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1

Tags: c#, json, facebook, json.net

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Facebook;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace facebook
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var client = new FacebookClient(acc_ess);
            dynamic result = client.Get("fql", new { q = "select target_id,target_type from connection where source_id = me()"});
            string jsonstring = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);

            //jsonstring {"data":[{"target_id":9503123,"target_type":"user"}]}
            List<RootObject> datalist = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(jsonstring);
        }

        public class Datum
        {
            public Int64 target_id { get; set; }
            public string target_type { get; set; }
        }

        public class RootObject
        {          
            public List<Datum> data { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"})
>   into type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[facebook.Program+RootObject]'
>   because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize
>   correctly. To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array
>   (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal
>   .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection
>   type like an array or List) that can be

I looked at other posts.

My json looks like this:

```
{"data":[{"target_id":9503123,"target_type":"user"}]}
```

Comment: There is *one* root object (`{"data": ..}`), not a list of them.

Comment: and how can just deserialize data contened into "data" root?

Answer (score 69):

To make it clear, in addition to @SLaks' answer, that meant you need to change this line :

```
List<RootObject> datalist = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(jsonstring);
```

to something like this :

```
RootObject datalist = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonstring);
```

Comment: This can't work, unless RootObject is already a List<>

Answer (score 25):

As the error message is trying very hard to tell you, you can't deserialize a single object into a collection (`List<>`).

You want to deserialize into a single `RootObject`.

Comment: What's confusing is why doesn't it just put nothing or a single value into an empty array and just "do it". If I do this using the old `DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(string[])).ReadObject()...` it just works, even if the string to deserialize to `string[]` is '{}'

Answer (score 6):

Can you try to change your json without `data` key like below?

```
[{"target_id":9503123,"target_type":"user"}]
```

Comment: [{"target_id":9503123,"target_type":"user"},{"target_id":9503123,"target_type":"user"}]  no outside curly brackets

Comment: @ddagsan - this is useful.

Answer (score 5):

That happened to me too, because I was trying to get an `IEnumerable` but the response had a single value. Please try to make sure it's a list of data in your response. The lines I used (for api url get) to solve the problem are like these:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/yourUrl");

if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    IEnumerable<RootObject> rootObjects =
        awaitresponse.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<RootObject>>();

    foreach (var rootObject in rootObjects)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(
            "{0}\t${1}\t{2}",
            rootObject.Data1, rootObject.Data2, rootObject.Data3);
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Hope It helps.

Answer (score 0):

The real problem is that you are using **dynamic** return type in the FacebookClient **Get method**. And although you use a method for serializing, the JSON converter cannot deserialize this Object after that.

Use insted of:

```
dynamic result = client.Get("fql", new { q = "select target_id,target_type from connection where source_id = me()"}); 
string jsonstring = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
```

something like that:

```
string result = client.Get("fql", new { q = "select target_id,target_type from connection where source_id = me()"}).ToString();
```

Then you can use **DeserializeObject** method:

```
var datalist = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(result);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

```
public partial class tree
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string sciencename { get; set; }
    public int familyid { get; set; }
}


private async void PopulateDataGridView()
{
    //For Single object response
    tree treeobj = new tree();
    treeobj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<tree>(Response);
    //For list of object response
    List<tree> treelistobj = new List<tree>();
    treelistobj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<tree>>(Response);
    //done
}
```

Comment: Add some context around your answer, instead of just posting code