# Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException for API

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

I keep getting an error after running the code for a few minutes

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException:
>   'Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[BitMEX.Order]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
>   To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3])

Can you please help me?

```
public List<Position> GetOpenPositions(string symbol)
{
    var param = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    string res = Query("GET", "/position", param, true);

    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Position>>(res)
        .Where(a => a.Symbol == symbol && a.IsOpen == true)
        .OrderByDescending(a => a.TimeStamp)
        .ToList();
}
```

Comment: You are getting this error because you are getting back an Object rather than an array, to check it try this `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Position>(res).Where(a => a.Symbol == symbol && a.IsOpen == true).OrderByDescending(a => a.TimeStamp)`

Comment: why you are doing `.ToList()` to your result? try removing it

Comment: @progrAmmar I suggest you to make your comment an answer, because it looks correct, and no one will answer it anymore. But this question will be marked as unanswered.

Comment: I tried removing .ToList() and it returns another error.

Comment: return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Position>(res)
        .Where(a => a.Symbol == symbol && a.IsOpen == true)
    .OrderByDescending(a => a.TimeStamp);
                Can you try this?

Comment: @jcjurevis - somewhere in your data model you have a `List<BitMEX.Order>` property that should just be a `BitMEX.Order` property.  Without your c# classes or your JSON that's all we can say, so this should be closed as a duplicate of [Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {“name”:“value”}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21358493/3744182) and [Using JsonConvert.DeserializeObject to deserialize Json to a C# POCO class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11126242/3744182).