# Binding JSON values in my server side is getting failed

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, list

I want to use the JSON values in my C# code. So I have written the code like below

```
public static void WriteToIEMService(string jsonValue)
    {
        string TimeFormatText = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        string strFileCreationDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
        string strFileName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IEM_SERVICEFILE"].ToString();

        try
        {            
           using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LogFileDirectory"].ToString() + strFileName + "_" + strFileCreationDate + ".txt"))
            {
                List<MasterServiceResponse> records = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MasterServiceResponse>>(jsonValue);
                
                sw.WriteLine("IEM Service started and send data to IEM below");

                foreach (MasterServiceResponse record in records)
               {
                   sw.WriteLine(record.SapId);
               }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            
            throw;
        }
    }
```

But I am getting error as

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[IPColoBilling_BKP.App_Code.MasterServiceResponse]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.

How can I fix this?

### Edit

My JSON values is as below

```
{"SiteData":[{"SAPId":"I-UW-SRPR-ENB-I001","SiteRFEIDate":"03-11-2014","SiteRFSDate":"03-11-2014","ID_OD":"ID","ID_ODchangeDate":"04-11-2018","NoofRRHBase":"0","RRHBaseChangeEffectiveDate":"","No_Of_Tenancy":"3","TenancyChangeEffectiveDate":"03-11-2014","SiteStatus":"Active","SiteDropDate":""}]}
```

### Update

```
public class MasterServiceResponse
{
    public string SapId { get; set; }
    public string AcknowledgementID { get; set; }
    public string FlagResponse { get; set; }
    public string ResponseMessage { get; set; }
    public string GisStatus { get; set; }
    public string GisSendDate { get; set; }
    public string SiteRFEIDate { get; set; }
    public string SiteRFSDate { get; set; }
    public string SiteRRHDate { get; set; }
    public string NoofRRHBase { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: one of your schema properties is defined as a collection, but it gets a single value only so fails

Comment: @JohnB: which one. ?

Comment: it would probably help to see the target class being deserialized to..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:** A stated by Panagiotis Kanavos, You are not creating Root object, so you have to restructure your models.

Don't know what your Model looks like, But this error message says your giving json object where it is expecting JSON array,

Below is the model you should be using

```
public class SiteData
{
    public string SAPId { get; set; }
    public string SiteRFEIDate { get; set; }
    public string SiteRFSDate { get; set; }
    public string ID_OD { get; set; }
    public string ID_ODchangeDate { get; set; }
    public string NoofRRHBase { get; set; }
    public string RRHBaseChangeEffectiveDate { get; set; }
    public string No_Of_Tenancy { get; set; }
    public string TenancyChangeEffectiveDate { get; set; }
    public string SiteStatus { get; set; }
    public string SiteDropDate { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<SiteData> SiteData { get; set; }
}
```

You also have to change the deserializing code

E.g.

```
RootObject records = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonValue);

foreach (SiteData record in records.SiteData)
{
   sw.WriteLine(record.SapId);
}
```

Comment: I cannot create again the class `SiteData`. I have already class as `MasterServiceResponse`.

Comment: Okay, then can you please attach your existing model here? so we can figure out what's wrong?

Comment: I have updated my question, have a look.. if u need anything else.. let me know

Comment: @BNN you *haven't* created a root class though. The JSON file contains an *object* whose `SiteData` property contains multiple `MasterServiceResponse` objects

Comment: Yes it is the issue "SiteData" is an object which contains the array of objects, List<MasterServiceResponse> expects an array of objects, so you have to update your models accordingly

Comment: ohh, so I need to create that too for using json values ??

Comment: Yes, and going forward you can use http://json2csharp.com to get exact models for your JSON

Comment: is this fine ? `List<MasterServiceResponse> records = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MasterServiceResponse>>(jsonValue);`

Comment: No, you have to change deserializing logic too, check updated answer.

Comment: Remember that you're deserializing the *whole* json file, not parts of it, every bit counts.

Comment: @MihirDave: `RootObject.SiteData` getting error as object reference is required in foreach

Comment: @MihirDave: now at foreach getting error as `Cannot convert type 'IPColoBilling_BKP.App_Code.SiteData' to 'IPColoBilling_BKP.App_Code.MasterServiceResponse'`

Comment: even I thought it should be like this `foreach (SiteData record in records.SiteData)`

Comment: yes mate, it worked perfectly fine now.. but whywas the `SiteData` giving issue

Comment: Good to Know, because I was saying records.SiteData is of type MasterServiceResponse which was wrong. and can you please accept the answer?

Answer (score 0):

As the error mentions, you cannot deserialize JSON object to list. So instead of:

```
List<MasterServiceResponse> records = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MasterServiceResponse>>(jsonValue);
```

You should update have something like:

```
MyObject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(jsonValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception message tells you that the JSON string contains single object, but you're tried to deserialize it into `List<MasterServiceResponse>` collection.

You should create a class to hold `List<MasterServiceResponse>`:

```
public class SiteData
{
    public List<MasterServiceResponse> MasterServiceResponse { get; set; }
}
```

Then you should replace this line:

```
List<MasterServiceResponse> records = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MasterServiceResponse>>(jsonValue);
```

to return single object like this:

```
SiteData records = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SiteData>(jsonValue);
```

Reference:

[Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21358493/cannot-deserialize-the-current-json-object-e-g-namevalue-into-type-sy)

Comment: if I use this, I am unable to use `foreach (MasterServiceResponse record in records)
                   {
                       sw.WriteLine(record.SapId);
                   }` and getting error

Answer (score -1):

Because your JSON start with a key `"SiteData"` which has an array value, you need to create a helper class to match that structure (e.g. `class SiteResponse`) with a property named `SiteData` of type `List<MasterServiceResponse>`.

**Code:**

```
public class SiteResponse
{
    public List<MasterServiceResponse> SiteData { get; set; }
}

private static void TestJson()
{
    var jsonValue = "{\"SiteData\":[{\"SAPId\":\"I-UW-SRPR-ENB-I001\",\"SiteRFEIDate\":\"03-11-2014\",\"SiteRFSDate\":\"03-11-2014\",\"ID_OD\":\"ID\",\"ID_ODchangeDate\":\"04-11-2018\",\"NoofRRHBase\":\"0\",\"RRHBaseChangeEffectiveDate\":\"\",\"No_Of_Tenancy\":\"3\",\"TenancyChangeEffectiveDate\":\"03-11-2014\",\"SiteStatus\":\"Active\",\"SiteDropDate\":\"\"}]}";

    var siteResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SiteResponse>(jsonValue);
    List<MasterServiceResponse> records = siteResponse.SiteData;
}
```

Working demo here:
**https://dotnetfiddle.net/wzg8AK**