# How to convert string to JSON returned by QnA Maker

Tags: c#, json, json.net, azure-qna-maker

I am currently required to create a script that needs to update the metadata of the  qna pairs in QnA Maker by matching the questions i have in an excel file. i am currently following the REST API guides:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/quickstarts/csharp

i have retrieved the qna pairs from QnA Maker already but since it returned a string value of all the qna information,  i need to convert it to JSON and match it against my List of QnA Objects i have retrieved from my excel files.

```
 public async static Task<string> GetQnAFromQnAMaker()
        {
            string getmethod = "/knowledgebases/{0}/{1}/qna/";
            var method_with_id = String.Format(getmethod, kbid, env);
            var uri = host + service + method_with_id;
            Console.WriteLine("Calling " + uri + ".");
            var response = await Get(uri);

            return response;

        }
```

i used NewtonSoft Deserialize object

```
List<FAQs> qnaMakerFaq = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<FAQs>>(qnaFromQnAMaker.Result);
```

but i get this error:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the
>   current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ExcelToQnAMaker.FAQs]' because the
>   type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly. To
>   fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3])
>   or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g.
>   not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array
>   or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object.
>   JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to
>   deserialize from a JSON object. Path 'qnaDocuments', line 2, position
>   17.'

my returned result string looks something like this...

> "{\r\n  \"qnaDocuments\": [\r\n    {\r\n      \"id\": ....

This is my FAQs Class

```
 public class FAQs
    {
        public List<string> Questions { get; set; }
        public string Answers { get; set; }
        public string Classification { get; set; }
        public string Division { get; set; }
        public int Spid { get; set; }
        public int Kbid { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: as the error clearly says your mapping object `FAQs` do not have any property named `qnaDocuments` which contains an array of data.

Comment: You are trying to deserialize to a collection but the root JSON container is an object, so you are getting the same error as in [Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {“name”:“value”}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21358493).  Your data model may also be wrong, see [How to auto-generate a C# class file from a JSON object string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21611674).  Any further help would require a [mcve], specifically the full JSON received.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at the API documentation for [Download Knowledgebase](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5a93fcf85b4ccd136866eb37/operations/knowledgebases_download) the response you get should look like

```
{
  "qnaDocuments": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "answer": "You can change the default message if you use the QnAMakerDialog. See this for details: https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/azure-bot-service/templates/qnamaker/#navtitle",
      "source": "Custom Editorial",
      "questions": [
        "How can I change the default message from QnA Maker?"
      ],
      "metadata": []
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "answer": "You can use our REST apis to manage your KB. See here for details: https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/58994a073d9e04097c7ba6fe/operations/58994a073d9e041ad42d9baa",
      "source": "Custom Editorial",
      "questions": [
        "How do I programmatically update my KB?"
      ],
      "metadata": [
        {
          "name": "category",
          "value": "api"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The model you're trying to deserialise to should match this structure...

```
public class KnowledgebaseResponse
{
    public List<KnowledgebaseItem> QnaDocuments { get; set; }
}

public class KnowledgebaseItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Answer { get; set; }
    public string Source { get; set; }
    public List<string> Questions { get; set; }
    public List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> MetaData { get; set; }
}
```

You can then deserialise the JSON correctly.

If you then want to do some mapping to your final model you'll have to do it as a extra step.