# Newtonsoft Json converter for json with filters

Tags: c#, json, json.net, converters

I am writing converter for json like this:

```
{
    "datatable": {
        "data": [
            [
                "A85002072C",
                "1994-11-15",
                678.9
            ]
        ],
        "columns": [
            {
                "name": "series_id",
                "type": "String"
            },
            {
                "name": "date",
                "type": "Date"
            },
            {
                "name": "value",
                "type": "double"
            }
        ]
    },
    "meta": {
        "next_cursor_id": null
    }
}
```

At the moment my converter looks like this:

```
    public class AbsToModelConverter : JsonConverter
    {

        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            return objectType.Name.Equals("AbsFseModel");
        }

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {

            JArray array = JArray.Load(reader);
            return new QuandlAbsModel
            {
                SeriesId = array[0].ToString(),
                Date = array[1].ToObject<DateTime>(),
                Value = array[2].ToObject<decimal?>()
            };
        }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            var orderItem = value as QuandlAbsModel;
            JArray arra = new JArray();
            arra.Add(orderItem.SeriesId);
            arra.Add(orderItem.Date);
            arra.Add(orderItem.Value);

            arra.WriteTo(writer);
        }
    }
```

It works at the moment, but when i am using filters my json can contain not full data, for example:

```
"data":[["1994-11-15",678.9]]
```

And my JsonConverter stops working, because there is no element array[2] and it throws error. Problem is that elements in data array don't have names (i get JSON from web API, so i can't change json at all). Is there any way to make my converter deserialize json with filters?

I have column names in my json after the data table, maybe this will help. But i don't understand how i can use them atm. Any advices?

Comment: Can you make sure the names in your C# code match what's in the JSON example? I think `AbsFseModel` corresponds to `data` and `QuandlAbsModel` corresponds to `datatable`?

Comment: When you are using filters such that your `data` array has fewer items, does the `columns` array in the JSON also have fewer items, corresponding to what is left in the `data`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JLRishe is correct that your problem is solvable without a custom converter. That's a good approach in many cases. If you're able to insert a translation over the JSON serializer/deserializer, it *might* be simpler to write, understand, and maintain than a custom JsonConverter. It's similar in spirit to the "serialization proxy pattern" used in the Java world. In essence, you're copying your data to a new serialization-specific object before serializing, and then doing the reverse to re-serialize.

This problem is solvable with a custom converter, and I've written an example to show that it can be done, but do consider using a translation proxy/layer first.

*This example is a proof-of-concept; not production-ready code.* I made very little effort to defend against malformed input or other errors. Its handling of the different fields/types is also very rudimentary--any changes to the fields/types will require changes to the converter. That sort of brittleness is likely to cause bugs and maintenance headaches over time.

To narrow down the problem a bit, I reduced the original question's sample JSON to its bare minimum:

```
{
  "datatable": {
    "data": [
      "A85002072C",
      "1994-11-15",
      678.9
    ],
    "columns": [
      {
        "name": "series_id"
      },
      {
        "name": "date"
      },
      {
        "name": "value"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

For reference, here's the C# class definition I'm deserializing to:

```cs
public class Model
{
    public string SeriesId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public Decimal? Value { get; set; }
}
```

And here's the proof-of-concept converter:

```cs
public sealed class ModelConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public static readonly ModelConverter Instance = new ModelConverter();

    private ModelConverter() {}

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) => objectType == typeof(Model);

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var obj = JObject.Load(reader);

        var data = (JArray)obj["datatable"]["data"];
        var columns = (JArray)obj["datatable"]["columns"];

        if (data.Count != columns.Count)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("data and columns must contain same number of elements");

        var model = new Model();

        for (int i = 0; i < data.Count; i++)
        {
            // A "switch" works well enough so long as the number of fields is finite and small.
            // There are smarter approaches, but I've kept the implementation basic
            // in order to focus on the core problem that was presented.
            switch (columns[i]["name"].ToString())
            {
                case "series_id":
                    model.SeriesId = data[i].ToString();
                    break;
                case "date":
                    model.Date = data[i].ToObject<DateTime>();
                    break;
                case "value":
                    model.Value = data[i].ToObject<decimal?>();
                    break;
            }
        }

        return model;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var data = new JArray();
        var columns = new JArray();

        var model = (Model)value;

        // Like the "switch" used in deserialization, these "if" blocks are
        // pretty rudimentary. There are better ways, but I wanted to keep
        // this proof-of-concept implementation simple.
        if (model.SeriesId != default(string))
        {
            data.Add(model.SeriesId);
            columns.Add(new JObject(new JProperty("name", "series_id")));
        }

        if (model.Date != default(DateTime))
        {
            data.Add(model.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
            columns.Add(new JObject(new JProperty("name", "date")));
        }

        if (model.Value != default(Decimal?))
        {
            data.Add(model.Value);
            columns.Add(new JObject(new JProperty("name", "value")));
        }

        var completeObj = new JObject();
        completeObj["datatable"] = new JObject();
        completeObj["datatable"]["data"] = data;
        completeObj["datatable"]["columns"] = columns;

        completeObj.WriteTo(writer);
    }
}
```

I wrote a few unit tests to verify the serializer. The tests are based on [xUnit.Net](https://github.com/xunit/xunit):

```cs
[Fact]
public void TestDeserializeSampleInputWithAllFields()
{
    var json = File.ReadAllText(BasePath + "sampleinput.json");

    var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Model>(json, ModelConverter.Instance);

    Assert.Equal("A85002072C", obj.SeriesId);
    Assert.Equal(new DateTime(1994, 11, 15), obj.Date);
    Assert.Equal(678.9M, obj.Value);
}

[Fact]
public void TestSerializeSampleInputWithAllFields()
{
    var model = new Model
    {
        SeriesId = "A85002072C",
        Date = new DateTime(1994, 11, 15),
        Value = 678.9M,
    };

    var expectedJson = File.ReadAllText(BasePath + "sampleinput.json");

    Assert.Equal(expectedJson, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model, Formatting.Indented, ModelConverter.Instance));
}
```

And to prove that the serializer works without all fields present:

```
{
  "datatable": {
    "data": [
      "B72008039G",
      543.2
    ],
    "columns": [
      {
        "name": "series_id"
      },
      {
        "name": "value"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

```cs
[Fact]
public void TestDeserializeSampleInputWithNoDate()
{
    var json = File.ReadAllText(BasePath + "sampleinput_NoDate.json");

    var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Model>(json, ModelConverter.Instance);

    Assert.Equal("B72008039G", obj.SeriesId);
    Assert.Equal(default(DateTime), obj.Date);
    Assert.Equal(543.2M, obj.Value);
}

[Fact]
public void TestSerializeSampleInputWithNoDate()
{
    var model = new Model
    {
        SeriesId = "B72008039G",
        Value = 543.2M,
    };

    var expectedJson = File.ReadAllText(BasePath + "sampleinput_NoDate.json");

    Assert.Equal(expectedJson, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model, Formatting.Indented, ModelConverter.Instance));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a `JsonConverter` for this.

Define classes to represent the parts of the JSON you need:

```
class APIResponse
{
    public DataTable DataTable { get; set; }
}

class DataTable
{
    public object[][] Data { get; set; }
}
```

Use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>()` to deserialize the JSON:

```
var parsed = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<APIResponse>(json);
```

Then get your values:

```
var rows = parsed.DataTable.Data.Select(r => new QuandLabsModel
{
    SeriesId = Convert.ToString(r[0]),
    Date = Convert.ToDateTime(r[1]),
    Value = Convert.ToDecimal(r[2])
});
```

Comment: Yeah, but i use converter because sometimes my JSON contains thousands of rows. For me it looks faster to convert directly into Model, than converting json -> object array (Data) -> Model. But need to test it to be sure. Anyway, thanks for great answer!