# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject error while deserializing a string

Tags: c#, json, .net, .net-6.0

I am trying to deserialize a json string that is coming from a js code, the data holds the json string that I want to deserialize.

The coming string is:

```
{"metalRingID":"FB11111","birdData":[{"longitude":-3.0851070084624497,"latitude":51.02832183751735,"gridRef":"ST2426","date":"2020-01-05T00:00:00"},{"longitude":-2.233409881591797,"latitude":51.5276985168457,"gridRef":null,"date":"2020-01-02T00:00:00"},{"longitude":-2.3790299892425537,"latitude":51.4547004699707,"gridRef":null,"date":"2020-01-03T00:00:00"},{"longitude":-1.6884700059890747,"latitude":51.68299865722656,"gridRef":null,"date":"2020-01-05T00:00:00"}]}
```

This is the model to hold that data:

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace BirdProject.Model.ViewModel
{
    public class birdDataSolutionVM
    {
        [JsonProperty("metalRingID")]
        public string metalRingID;

        [JsonProperty("birdData")]
        public List<birdRecordVM> birdData;
    }
}
```

This is the line that should do the job.

```
var birdRecords = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<birdDataSolutionVM>>(data);
```

The error I am receiving is the next:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"})
> into type
> 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[BirdProject.Model.ViewModel.birdDataSolutionVM]'
> because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize
> correctly.\nTo fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array
> (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal
> .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection
> type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON
> object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it
> to deserialize from a JSON object.\nPath 'metalRingID', line 1,
> position 15.

Comment: That root JSON is not an array, it's a single object that contains an array of birdData

Comment: You are trying to deserialize a `birdDataSolutionVM`, not a list of them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List\`1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21358493/cannot-deserialize-the-current-json-object-e-g-namevalue-into-type-sy)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be deserializing into the type, not an array of the type. It's a single object containing an array, but the root json is not an array.

```
var birdRecords = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<birdDataSolutionVM>(data);
```